# Calculating worklist with live variable analysis

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I am struggling with the calculation of the [worklist](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4120/2011fa/lectures/lec21-fa11.pdf) algorithm, I do not want to implement the iterative algorithm as so many redundant steps it takes.

The algorithm I am following to calculate the worklist for live variables is as below
[image]

Can anybody explain to me for the example given below, what would be the initial worklist and how the worklist algorithm would be applied to this?

```
x = 1   /*block 1*/
y = 23  /*block 2*/
x = 100 /*block 3*/
print x+y /*block 4*/
```

I have calculated these many equations for In[n] block only, apart from this I am not getting how to construct a worklist, which nodes shall I insert into it and when shall I remove particular nodes from the worklist in order to make it empty at the end.

```
in[4] = use[4] U (out[4] - def[4])
   = {x, y} U { }
in[3] = use[3] U (out[3] - def[3])
   = { } U { y }
in[2] = use[2] U (out[2] - def[2])
   = { } U { y } - { y }
in[1] = use[1] U (out[1] - def[1])
   = { } U {  }
```

I am using [Nilson's Algorithms chap-6](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/%7Ehrni/PPA/slides6.pdf) to understand this concept. Here they have given an explanation for reaching definition ([slide 15](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/%7Ehrni/PPA/slides6.pdf)), but I am interested in the live variable analysis for the worklist.

Comment: One of the best ways to learn how an algorithm works is to implement it with a programming language then give it a good set of test cases. It seems you have done the best part of learning how to code an algorithm by working through it with pen and paper. If I were doing this I would use Prolog.

Comment: This might help. [Connected Components visualizer](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/JavascriptVisual/ConnectedComponent.html)

Comment: @GuyCoder Thank you for your inputs, I figured out how the worklist works for live variables. Here, out[n] is nothing but successor nodes that are having live variables at their entry. If we figured out available live variables in successors, then this algorithm works. I'll also post my answer soon with a detailed evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the working of above algorithm on your example.

```
Work list is a queue. initial values of in,out of all blocks are {}
Initial work list has blocks {1,2,3,4}
Remove the first element from the work list and compute
 out[1] = U in[succ(1)]  = in[2] = {}
 in[1]  = use[1] U { out[1]-def[1]} = {} U{{}-{x}} = {} No change in in[1]
Work list has {2,3,4}
Remove the first element from the work list and compute
 out[2] = U in[succ(2)] = in[3] ={}
 in[2]  = use[2] U {out[2]-def[2]} = {} U {{}-{y}} = {} No change in in[2]
Work list has {3,4}
Remove the first element from the work list and compute
 out[3] = U in[succ(3)] = in[4] = {}
 in[3] = use[3] U {out[3]-def[3]} = {}U{{}-{x}} = {} No change in in[3]
Work list has {4},
Remove the first element from the work list and compute
 out[4] = U in[nosucc] = {}
 in[4] = use[4] U {out[4] - def[3]} = {x,y} U {{}-{}} = {x,y} 
change in in[4]( previous value is empty, it has to be propagated to its   
predecessors)  add its predecessor to work list.
Work list has {3},
remove the first element from the work list and compute
 out[3] = U in[succ(3)] = in[4] = {x,y}
 in[3] = use[3] U {out[3]-def[3]} = {}U{{x,y}-{x}} = {y}
change in in[3]( previous value is empty, it has to be propagated to its 
predecessors)  add its predecessor to work list.   
Work list has {2}, 
remove the first element from the work list and compute
 out[2] = U in[succ(2)] = in[3] ={y}
 in[2]  = use[2] U {out[2]-def[2]} = {} U {{y}-{y}} = {} No change in in[2]
Work list is empty, it stops
```

Final values:

```
 out[4]={},  in[4]={x,y}
 out[3]={x,y}  in[3]={y}
 out[2]={y}     in[2]={}
 out[1]={}      in[1]={}
```

The value of 'x' computed at block 1 is not live(not used after, it can be eleminated)

Comment: As this is a live variable analysis, I think I need to take all nodes from bottom to top in the worklist. (4, 3, 2, 1). So that there would not be a need for extra iterations, and the worklist will get empty for only one time

Comment: Answer was given based on the Algorithm given in question and reference link given. In fact the Algorithm can be further improved                                                                        a) initial worklist W = { set of all nodes} can be replaced by nodes with use[n] not empty. Nodes which generate live-ness information.